# what happens when I use a global map variable in scala without broadcasting

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In scala, what happens when I use a global map variable in scala without broadcasting?

E.g. if I get a variable using `collect*` (such as `collectAsMap`), it seems it is a global variable, and I can use it in all `RDD.mapValues()` functions without explicitly broadcasting it.

BUT I know spark works distributedly, and it should not be able to process a global memory-stored variable without broadcasting it. So, what happened?

Code example (this code call tf-idf in text, where df is stored in a Map):

```
//dfMap is a String->int Map in memory
//Array[(String, Int)] = Array((B,2), (A,3), (C,1))
val dfMap = dfrdd.collectAsMap;
//tfrdd is a rdd, and I can use dfMap in its mapValues function
//tfrdd: Array((doc1,Map(A -> 3.0)), (doc2,Map(A -> 2.0, B -> 1.0)))
val tfidfrdd = tfrdd.mapValues( e => e.map(x => x._1 -> x._2 * lineNum / dfMap.getOrElse(x._1, 1) ) ); 
tfidfrdd.saveAsTextFile("/somedir/result/");
```

The code works just fine. My question is what happened there? Does the driver send the dfMap to all workers just like broadcasting or else?

What's the difference if I code broadcasting explicitely like this:

```
dfMap = sc.broadcast(dfrdd.collectAsMap)
val tfidfrdd = tfrdd.mapValues( e => e.map(x => x._1 -> x._2 * lineNum / dfMap.value.getOrElse(x._1, 1) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked more resources and aggregating others' answers and put it in order. The difference between using an external variable DIRECTLY(as my so called "global variable"), and BROADCASTING a variable using sc.broadcast() is like this:

1) When using external variable directly, spark will send a copy of the serialized variable together with each TASK. Whereas by sc.broadcast, the variable is sent one copy per EXECUTOR. The number of Task is normally 10 times larger than the Executor.

So when the variable (say a map) is large enough (more than 20K), the former operation may cost a lot time on network transformation and cause frequent GC, which slows the spark down. Hence large variable(>20K) is suggested to be broadcasted explicitly.

2) When using external variable directly the variable is not persisted, it ends with the task and thus can not be reused. Whereas by sc.broadcast() the variable is auto-persisted in the executors' memory, it lasts until you explicitly unpersist it. Thus sc.broadcast variable is available across tasks and stages.

So if the variable is expected to be used multiple times, sc.broadcast() is suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between a Global Map Variable and a Broadcast variable. If we use a global variable in a map function of an RDD then it will be broadcasted to all nodes. For example:

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[4] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> rdd.filter(elem => list.contains(elem)).collect
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at <console>:29
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 3 (collect at <console>:29) with 4 output partitions
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 3 (collect at <console>:29)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG DAGScheduler: submitStage(ResultStage 3)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG DAGScheduler: missing: List()
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 3 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at filter at <console>:29), which has no missing parents
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG DAGScheduler: submitMissingTasks(ResultStage 3)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.0 KB, free 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Put block broadcast_4 locally took  1 ms
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_4 without replication took  1 ms
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.5 KB, free 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on 192.168.2.123:37645 (size: 2.5 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_4_piece0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Told master about block broadcast_4_piece0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Put block broadcast_4_piece0 locally took  2 ms
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG ContextCleaner: Got cleaning task CleanBroadcast(1)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_4_piece0 without replication took  2 ms
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG ContextCleaner: Cleaning broadcast 1
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TorrentBroadcast: Unpersisting TorrentBroadcast 1
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 4 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 4 missing tasks from ResultStage 3 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at filter at <console>:29)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG DAGScheduler: New pending partitions: Set(0, 1, 2, 3)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 3.0 with 4 tasks
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TaskSetManager: Epoch for TaskSet 3.0: 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TaskSetManager: Valid locality levels for TaskSet 3.0: NO_PREF, ANY
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_3.0, runningTasks: 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5886 bytes)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 13, localhost, executor driver, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5886 bytes)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14, localhost, executor driver, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5886 bytes)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 15, localhost, executor driver, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5886 bytes)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG Executor: Task 12's epoch is 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_4
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_4 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 13)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: removing broadcast 1
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Removing broadcast 1
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Removing block broadcast_1
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 15)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG Executor: Task 13's epoch is 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 of size 5112 dropped from memory (free 384072627)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Removing block broadcast_1_piece0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 of size 2535 dropped from memory (free 384075162)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 192.168.2.123:37645 in memory (size: 2.5 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Told master about block broadcast_1_piece0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_4
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_4 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG Executor: Task 14's epoch is 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_4
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_4 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG Executor: Task 15's epoch is 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_4
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_4 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: Done removing broadcast 1, response is 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG ContextCleaner: Cleaned broadcast 1
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG ContextCleaner: Got cleaning task CleanBroadcast(3)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG ContextCleaner: Cleaning broadcast 3
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TorrentBroadcast: Unpersisting TorrentBroadcast 3
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: removing broadcast 3
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Removing broadcast 3
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Removing block broadcast_3_piece0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 of size 3309 dropped from memory (free 384078471)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: Sent response: 0 to 192.168.2.123:40909
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on 192.168.2.123:37645 in memory (size: 3.2 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_3_piece0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Told master about block broadcast_3_piece0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManager: Removing block broadcast_3
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 of size 6904 dropped from memory (free 384085375)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 13). 912 bytes result sent to driver
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: Done removing broadcast 3, response is 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: Sent response: 0 to 192.168.2.123:40909
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_3.0, runningTasks: 3
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TaskSetManager: No tasks for locality level NO_PREF, so moving to locality level ANY
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 13) in 36 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/4)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14). 912 bytes result sent to driver
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG ContextCleaner: Cleaned broadcast 3
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_3.0, runningTasks: 2
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12). 912 bytes result sent to driver
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14) in 36 ms on localhost (executor driver) (2/4)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 15). 908 bytes result sent to driver
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_3.0, runningTasks: 1
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_3.0, runningTasks: 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 15) in 36 ms on localhost (executor driver) (3/4)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12) in 45 ms on localhost (executor driver) (4/4)
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 3.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 3 (collect at <console>:29) finished in 0.045 s
17/03/16 10:21:53 DEBUG DAGScheduler: After removal of stage 3, remaining stages = 0
17/03/16 10:21:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: collect at <console>:29, took 0.097564 s
res4: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

In above log we can clearly see that global variable `list` is broadcasted . So, is the case when we explicitly broadcast the `list`.

```
scala> val br = sc.broadcast(list)
17/03/16 10:26:40 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 160.0 B, free 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:26:40 DEBUG BlockManager: Put block broadcast_5 locally took  1 ms
17/03/16 10:26:40 DEBUG BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_5 without replication took  1 ms
17/03/16 10:26:40 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 227.0 B, free 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:26:40 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on 192.168.2.123:37645 (size: 227.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:26:40 DEBUG BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_5_piece0
17/03/16 10:26:40 DEBUG BlockManager: Told master about block broadcast_5_piece0
17/03/16 10:26:40 DEBUG BlockManager: Put block broadcast_5_piece0 locally took  1 ms
17/03/16 10:26:40 DEBUG BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_5_piece0 without replication took  1 ms
17/03/16 10:26:40 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 5 from broadcast at <console>:26
br: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[List[Int]] = Broadcast(5)

scala> rdd.filter(elem => br.value.contains(elem)).collect
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at <console>:31
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at <console>:31) with 4 output partitions
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at <console>:31)
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG DAGScheduler: submitStage(ResultStage 0)
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG DAGScheduler: missing: List()
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at filter at <console>:31), which has no missing parents
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG DAGScheduler: submitMissingTasks(ResultStage 0)
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 6.7 KB, free 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG BlockManager: Put block broadcast_1 locally took  6 ms
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_1 without replication took  6 ms
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.2 KB, free 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 192.168.2.123:37303 (size: 3.2 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG BlockManager: Told master about block broadcast_1_piece0
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG BlockManager: Put block broadcast_1_piece0 locally took  2 ms
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_1_piece0 without replication took  2 ms
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 4 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at filter at <console>:31)
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG DAGScheduler: New pending partitions: Set(0, 1, 2, 3)
17/03/16 10:27:50 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 4 tasks
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG TaskSetManager: Epoch for TaskSet 0.0: 0
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG TaskSetManager: Valid locality levels for TaskSet 0.0: NO_PREF, ANY
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
17/03/16 10:27:50 DEBUG TaskSetManager: Valid locality levels for TaskSet 0.0: NO_PREF, ANY
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5885 bytes)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5885 bytes)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5885 bytes)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5885 bytes)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG Executor: Task 0's epoch is 0
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG Executor: Task 2's epoch is 0
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG Executor: Task 3's epoch is 0
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG Executor: Task 1's epoch is 0
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_1
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_1 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_1
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_1 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_1
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_1 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_1
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_1 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_0
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_0 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_0
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_0 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_0
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_0 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_0
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_0 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3). 908 bytes result sent to driver
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2). 999 bytes result sent to driver
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 912 bytes result sent to driver
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 912 bytes result sent to driver
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 3
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG TaskSetManager: No tasks for locality level NO_PREF, so moving to locality level ANY
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 2
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 1
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 165 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/4)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) in 180 ms on localhost (executor driver) (2/4)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 249 ms on localhost (executor driver) (3/4)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 186 ms on localhost (executor driver) (4/4)
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at <console>:31) finished in 0.264 s
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/03/16 10:27:51 DEBUG DAGScheduler: After removal of stage 0, remaining stages = 0
17/03/16 10:27:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at <console>:31, took 0.381615 s
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Same is the case with Broadcast variable.

Comment: It seems the two broadcasting procedual is different from log, although both has the key word "broadcast".  I find some info from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Comment: quot: "Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks. They can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large input dataset in an efficient manner. Spark also attempts to distribute broadcast variables using efficient broadcast algorithms to reduce communication cost."

Comment: I don't know if I understand it right. It seems like this to me: global variable is sent to each node with the task, and is cleaned once the task is done; Whereas explicitly broadcast send the virable to each server/node all at once, and is persisted until you explicity unpersist it or the spark program ends. Thus the later could be shared between stages.

Comment: Yes @SimonSu, you are right. Spark automatically broadcasts the common data needed by tasks within each stage. The data broadcasted this way is cached in serialized form and deserialized before running each task. This means that explicitly creating broadcast variables is only useful when tasks across multiple stages need the same data or when caching the data in deserialized form is important.

Answer (score 1):

When you broadcast, the data is cached by all the nodes. so when you are performing an action (collect, saveAsTextFile, head) operation the broadcasted values are already available to all the worker nodes.

But if you do not broadcast the value, when performing an action each worker node needs to perform a shuffle to get the data from the driver node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't think my former program triggled shuffle before using broadcast explictly.

Answer (score 1):

First off it is a spark thing - not a scala one

The diff is values are broadcasted everytime they are used whereas explicit broadcasts are cached.

> "Broadcast variables are created from a variable v by calling
>   SparkContext.broadcast(v). The broadcast variable is a wrapper around
>   v, and its value can be accessed by calling the value method ... After the broadcast variable is created, it should
>   be used instead of the value v in any functions run on the cluster so
>   that v is not shipped to the nodes more than once"

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But I don't quite get the diff “the global ones are set before the computations”. It seems to me in my e.g. program the global dfMap I use is calculate during process(CollectAsMap from a realtime caculated RDD). And explicitly broadcasting it doesn't seem to be different in terms of "during and before" the computation.

Comment: Do you mean that global viarant is only broadcasted until the next action, and explicit broadcasting trigger the broadcast instantly?